# execute() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given for db.execute() flask psql insertion

Tags: python, flask, psql

I have the following code to insert a row of data into psql database:

```
values = (name,price,category,description,image)
app.db.execute("INSERT INTO Player(name, price, position, description, image) VALUES (%s,%f,%s,%s,%s)",values)
app.db.commit()
```

However, I get the execute() error even though I am only putting in 2 parameters into the execute() function. Any help? I have also tried the following insertion method and still get the same error, so do not think it is a syntax error.

```
app.db.execute("INSERT INTO Player (name,price,position,description,image) VALUES (:name,:price,:category,:description,:image)",{"name": name, "price": price, "category":category,"description":description,"image":image})
```

any help is appreciated. Thank you!
Am using SQLAlchemy for app.db.execute()

Comment: Looks like a typo here: `VALUES (%s,%f,%s,%s,%s)`, did you mean `%f`?

Answer (score 0):

Use parameterized queries to solve this issue

```
statement = "INSERT INTO Player(name, price, position, description, image) VALUES (%s,%f,%s,%s,%s)"
app.db.execute(statement, values)
```

Comment: Good idea, but no luck. Still get execute() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given error for the new line app.db.execute(qry,values).